# How to store and retrieve data of last 30 days from SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to retrieve data of last week or 30 days from my SQLite database, and show it in a `ListView`. I tried different queries but did not get result. So how can I get data of only last 30 days?

Create database table query :

```
public String CREATE_DATA_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_DATA+"("
            + DATE + " TEXT," + TIME+ " TEXT,"+STEPS + " TEXT,"+CALORIES +" TEXT," +
            DISTANCE+ " TEXT"+")";
```

Storing data :

```
public boolean storeData(String date,String time,long stepsTaken,
                          long caloriesBurned, String distanceCovered){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(DATE, date);
        values.put(TIME, time);
        values.put(STEPS, stepsTaken);
        values.put(CALORIES, caloriesBurned);
        values.put(DISTANCE, distanceCovered);
        long result=db.insert(TABLE_DATA,null, values);
        if(result==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Getting data, the query I try to retrieve data is in comment line :

```
public ArrayList<User> getData(){

        calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        date=dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        ArrayList<User> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
        //String query="SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_DATA+" WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now','-30 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime')";
        //Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
       Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_DATA,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String date=cursor.getString(0);
            String time=cursor.getString(1);
            long steps=cursor.getLong(2);
            long calories=cursor.getLong(3);
            String distance=cursor.getString(4);
            User user=new User(date,time,steps,calories,distance);
            arrayList.add(user);
        }


        return arrayList;

    }
```

The way I get date and time :

```
calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                    dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    timeFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    date=dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                    time=timeFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
is it anyway that we can only store data of last 30 days
```

Comment: What is the format of the values stored in the date column?

Comment: i already mention it its "dd-MM-yyyy"

Comment: @WaqasFarooq change the format of your stored date to "yyyy-MM-dd" and then your SELECT statement will work.

Comment: You'll also need to use `date()` instead of `datetime()` after fixing the stored date like @forpas said. Both sides of the comparison expression need to use the same format.

Comment: Personally, though, instead of having separate columns for date and time I'd just use one, probably using Unix seconds instead of a string as it's smaller to store and faster to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that as the date column starts with the **Day** then this will be the first character compared so ***02-01-1900** is greater than **01-12-2018**. This is further complicated as you are using the **datetime** function that returns the date as YYYY-MM-DD so you are comparing 01-01-1990 with 2018-11-11 (less). However 21-01-1990 would be higher than 2018-11-11 (i.e. 21 is higher than 20).

Therefore you MUST have the dates in the same format for a comparison or sort to return results consistent with expectations.

You have two core solutions :-

1. Amend your code to store the dates in a a supported format, which just so happens to also suit comparisons and sorting (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD) see [Time Strings - SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

   - In which case you query would then work if the date function rather then the datetime function were used as per `String query="SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_DATA+" WHERE date BETWEEN datee('now','localtime','-30 days') AND date('now', 'localtime')";`
2. Reformat the date retrieved from the date column dynamically. e.g. by using :-

   `SELECT * FROM table_data WHERE 
       substr(date,7,4)||substr(date,3,4)||substr(date,1,2) 
       BETWEEN date('now','localtime','-30 days') AND date('now','localtime')
   ;`

   - Note likewise you should apply the use of **localtime** consistently (as the above does, bar the date retrieved from the table which should have localtime applied when storing the value).

#### Proof of Concept

The following is some SQL that could be copied and pasted to an SQLite tool to show that the second option above works :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_data;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_data (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT);
INSERT INTO table_data (date) VALUES
  (substr(date('now','localtime','-50 days'),9,2)||substr(date('now','localtime','-50 days'),5,4)||substr(date('now','localtime','-50 days'),1,4)),
    (substr(date('now','localtime','-40 days'),9,2)||substr(date('now','localtime','-40 days'),5,4)||substr(date('now','localtime','-40 days'),1,4)),
    (substr(date('now','localtime','-30 days'),9,2)||substr(date('now','localtime','-30 days'),5,4)||substr(date('now','localtime','-30 days'),1,4)),
    (substr(date('now','localtime','-20 days'),9,2)||substr(date('now','localtime','-20 days'),5,4)||substr(date('now','localtime','-20 days'),1,4)),
    (substr(date('now','localtime','-10 days'),9,2)||substr(date('now','localtime','-10 days'),5,4)||substr(date('now','localtime','-10 days'),1,4))
;
-- Result 1 (the data as loaded)
SELECT * FROM table_data; 

-- Result2 Data extracted using BETWEEN
SELECT * FROM table_data 
    WHERE 
    substr(date,7,4)||substr(date,3,4)||substr(date,1,2) 
    BETWEEN date('now','localtime','-30 days') AND date('now','localtime')
;

-- Result 3 data from 30 days ago on
SELECT * FROM table_data WHERE 
    substr(date,7,4)||substr(date,3,4)||substr(date,1,2) >= date('now','localtime','-30 days')
;
```

### Results :-

#### Result 1

[image]

- *(rows 3,4 & 5 with 30 days)*

#### Result 2

[image]

#### Result 3

[image]

Although more time and space has been given to option 2. It is suggested that Option1 is by far the better option as it will reduce unnecessary complexity and be more efficient.